# How to uniquely identity a pipedrive account?

Tags: pipedrive-api

We are trying to integrate our platform with *Pipedrive*. As far as we have researched, in a pipedrive account, there is one **admin** and he can add multiple **users**. And the users later can login in their respective accounts.

What we are trying to make sure is that once a Pipedrive account is integrated with our platform, the same account should not be integrated twice. So, I need a unique identifier, that lets me know whether the account has already been integrated.

My initial approach was to check the api key. But it was not successful, since every users in an account have different API Keys.

After a bit of research, I found out that there is an identifier called **company_id** which is common for all the users in an account. But I could not find anything regarding it in documentation. So, I am not 100% confident to go ahead and implement it in our code.

Does anyone have an idea about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipedrive support rep here.

The most sure-fire way to ensure this is to make a GET request against `http://api.pipedrive.com/v1/users?api_token=your_token_here`.

You are correct in assuming the `company_id` in the `additional_data` object in the response is static and won't change across any users on the account.

Note that a Pipedrive account may have more than one admin, and that non-admins (regular users) might have visibility (and editing) restrictions in place, which may cause some of your `GET`, `PUT` and `DELETE` requests to fail.

In case you're not doing this already, I'd thus advise filtering the `data` array from the abovementioned endpoint for `user.is_you` to equal `true` and check whether the `is_admin` property is set to `1` during "registration" to ensure the user setting up the integration is an admin.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank for the answer.. Your suggestion to check whether the user is admin or not is very helpful. I will incorporate it in my code. Once again thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking for. Are you looking for a unique identifier for each user?

Each user has an id, you can get all users by calling

> https://api.pipedrive.com/v1/users?api_token=____

This will return a JSON Object with data on your users, including their names and associated IDs. Admins are just users with different privilege levels. All admins are users, but not all users are admins. All users are part of a company, the company is identified by the first part of the Pipedrive account url ie.

> https://FooCompany.pipedrive.com

Are you trying to see if a certain company has been integrated already?

Comment: I would suggest then using the first url I listed. Each user has an ID and can belong to multiple Pipedrive accounts. The User ID persists across each account.